# Vim replace inside quotes

Tags: vim

Many times I find that I will will want to yank the content between quotes and paste them inside another set up of quotes. For example, take this code for instance.

```
var foo = 'bar',
    baz = 'buz';
```

I would normally do a `yi'` inside of `'bar'` to yank the word **bar**.

How do I replace **buz** with my yank? I know one option is to do a `di'"0P`, I just wonder if there is an easier solution I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With your cursor anywhere on the word `buz`, `vi'p` to visually select inside the quotes and then put the contents of the most recent yank.

Comment: @ShaneStillwell, read `:help text-objects` to learn how does that work. Also, you might like plugin 'surround': http://goo.gl/s9x4F .

Comment: it actually also works when the cursor is on the quote character `'`

Answer (score 2):

I need this so often, I wrote a plugin to simplify and allow maximum speed: [ReplaceWithRegister](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703).

This plugin offers a two-in-one `gr` command that replaces text covered by a {motion} / text object, entire line(s) or the current selection with the contents of a register; the old text is deleted into the black-hole register, i.e. it's gone. It transparently handles many corner cases and allows for a quick repeat via the standard `.` command. Should you not like it, its page has links to alternatives.

Comment: I think I could get used to this. So that's both a positive and a risk :)

Answer (score 0):

also note after you replace the content in visual mode,the content being replaced will now in you register. command :reg will show it.
In your example, command `p` will paste the `buz` in the editor.